# Shorthand for null-coalescing operator and assignment for re-generatable property?

Tags: swift, swift2, null-coalescing-operator

In my property, I am assigning a value to a property before returning it. Next time it is accessed, it is checking if it is `nil` and assigning it again or just returning the instance.

This is how I'm doing it now:

```
private var _myProp: MyInstance?

public var myProp: MyInstance {
    if _myProp == nil {
        _myProp = MyInstance()
    }
    return _myProp!
}
```

This look very un-Swift like and was hoping for a more elegant way of doing this. For example, in `C#` I can do this:

```
private var _myProp: MyInstance?

public var myProp: MyInstance {
    return _myProp ?? (_myProp = MyInstance())
}
```

I'm trying to allow the property re-generatable so it can be deallocated, but next time it is accessed it will create the instance once again.

Anything like this in Swift?

Comment: The inner property needs the ability to be reset to `nil`?

Comment: What about `lazy var myProp = MyInstance()` ? – Edit: That is probably what Josh is thinking about.

Comment: But if I do `myProp = nil` somewhere, it won't re-generate the instance correct? I'm trying to make the property re-generatable so if it is made `nil`, it will auto-create the instance again.

Comment: Correct. – `return _myProp ?? { _myProp = MyInstance() ; return _myProp! }()` would work.

Comment: oh wow good idea!

Comment: I wonder if a custom operator can do this, like a new `return _myProp ??= MyInstance()`

Comment: That would be possible (and I think there was a Q&A about it – difficult to find :). But it would require an `inout` argument on the LHS, which means that the property is read *and written to* in any case.

Comment: I was just thinking the other day that Swift needs an `??=` operator. This would be parallel to the use of `||=` in Ruby, for example, to assign a value only if no value has been assigned. Feel free to file an enhancement request with Apple!

Comment: @matt: [SE-0024 Optional Value Setter ??=](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0024-optional-value-setter.md) has already been rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar notation in Swift would be:

```
private var _myProp: MyInstance?

public var myProp: MyInstance {
    return _myProp ?? {_myProp = MyInstance(); return _myProp!}()
}
```

But I don't know that it's really more Swift-like or common to see that...

If you use this pattern a lot, it's probably best to just create a global function to help, like this:

```
func retrieve<T>(_ property:inout T?, withDefault value:T)->T {
    if property == nil {
        property = value
    }
    return property!
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
private var _myProp: MyInstance?

public var myProp: MyInstance {
    return retrieve(&_myProp, withDefault:MyInstance())
}
```

In my experience, functions are generally easier for other people to understand, read and debug than custom operators or overloads.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Unless it is a class.

Comment: Oh, that's true, @MartinR. Silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

Swift does have the null-coalescing operator, so you can get awfully close to your C# code like so:

```
private var _myProp: MyInstance?

public var myProp: MyInstance {
    mutating get {
        _myProp = _myProp ?? MyInstance()
        return _myProp!
    }
}
```

The assignment operator in Swift evaluates to `Void`, not the assigned value, so you can't just use that for your `return` statement.

Comment: But this would do an assignment `_myProp = _myProp` even if the property is already set. Not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

In light of your replies, I think this is the "swiftiest" way to do this:

```
private var _property: MyClass? = nil
public var property: MyClass {
    if let property = _property {
        return property
    } else {
        let property = MyClass()
        _property = property
        return property
    }
}
```

It's probably more verbose than you'd like, but in exchange for that I think it's pretty clear and it doesn't force-unwraps any optionals.

Comment: Because internally to my class, I'd like to deallocate `_myProp` and make it `nil`, but if this property is accessed from the outside it will re-create the instance automatically.

Comment: Is this for performance reasons? If you just want the variable to be reset, you can make it a var, and instead of setting it to nil, you can set it to a new instance.

Comment: Well because it's public I don't want to allow consumer to change the variable by making it `var`.

Comment: Performance in the sense that I want to deallocate and free up the memory when not needed, but next time it is accessed it will recreate it lazily.

Comment: Updated my answer, it's not the most compact code, but it's pretty explicit and swifty.